# Update ODBC DB through Excel

Tags: excel, odbc

I am able to query and view table through excel, but I was wondering if there is a way to directly update or insert by modifying data in the excel.

Similar to Microsoft Access Linked table, maybe?

Comment: The question is toooooooo broad and will be very much likely closed. Try to reedit and be more specific.

Comment: I think no. For this you have to establish a connection to the ms access db and then fire insert.

Comment: Which ODBC ? Table in what kind of database? Without such a minimal info, the only response is YES, which won't get you far.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use VBA, ADODB, and the data driver to write a custom application to do this.  But there is nothing built in to Excel for writing back to an ODBC data source.  QueryTables in Excel are read-only.